# How to observe a Variable from another Variable or Observable?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Suppose I have an `var id = Variable<Int>(0)`. I want to observe changes to it from another Variable or Observable called team (`var team = Observable<Team>`). the team observable will be observed by the view controller and will update the UI there. Therefore, the id variable serves only to create/update (through creating `Team(id: id)` ) the value of the team observable.

I have been trying multiple approaches such as `combineLatest` or `subscribe` but I always get compile error saying:

> Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter

What's going on?

Comment: Can you try and further explain what you're trying to do here? The question is a bit unclear. Also some code of what you have tried would be great :)

Comment: [rgoncalv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6096029/rgoncalv) did either of the answers posted below solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance of `Team(id:)` is most likely a struct which are passed by value (Value Type) not by reference (Reference Type), therefore it cannot capture `self` while off of the main thread. See "Classes and Structures" in the [swift programming guide](https://swift.org/documentation/)

Change your Structure to a Class and it should work as expected: [Simple observable struct with RxSwift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460542/simple-observable-struct-with-rxswift)